# Is double counts in SELECT allowed in couchbase analytics query

Tags: analytics, couchbase, sql++

I am getting 500 for following query

```
SELECT count(*), count(DISTINCT(member)) FROM datasetName
```

If i run each count in separate query it works fine

Comment: You're getting 500 what? A 500 HTTP error? Could you be more specific about what error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which Couchbase Server version are you using?

If 6.0 then try the following workaround:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t2.c2
FROM 
(SELECT count(*) c1 FROM test) t1,
(SELECT count(DISTINCT(member)) c2 FROM test) t2
```

If 6.5 then your query should work as is.